# Test for disappearance of element times out

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to test the disappearance of element with `react-testing-library`. The element is `Spin` of `antd`.

I have a container `SpinnerContainer.js` which connects to redux store, and component `Spinner.js` to render the result.

When `SpinnerContainer` is mounted it dispatches the action `FETCH_USER` and on success returns the value and set the loading `state` to false, which removes the loading icon.

The problem is `waitForElementToBeRemoved` from `react-testing-library` times out.

`SpinnerContainer.js`

```
state = {
  loading: false
};

componentDidMount() {
   this.setState({
     loading: true
   });

   this.callToSaga();
}

callToSaga() {
  const { dispatch } = this.props;

    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      dispatch({
        type: actions.FETCH_USER,
        resolve,
        reject
      });
    }).then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.setState({ loading: false });
    }).catch(error => console.log(error);
}
```

But if I don't dispatch the action to call `FETCH_USER`, and change the loading `state`. The test passed.

`SpinnerContainer.js`

```
// Without call to saga

state = {
  loading: true
};

componentDidMount() {
   setTimeout(() => {
     this.setState({
       loading: false
     });
  }, 200)
}
```

I have made demo in code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-wildflower-012lj?from-embed

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The problem was with creating the store for testing. Once I created the store with `applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)`, the problem got fixed.

`SpinnerContainer.test.js`

```
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware));
sagaMiddleware.run(saga);
```

I have updated the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-wildflower-012lj?from-embed